# What is the best option to make my .NET UI application scriptable?

Tags: c#, .net, scripting, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

I have .NET application and would like to allow users to write macros.

Any easy to use language would do.

However, I don't want to write a compiler, interpreter, debugger.

I know there are many options on the net but most solutions seem clunky.

What is my best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into [Visual Studio Tools for Applications (VSTA)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa700828.aspx).  I looked at this a couple of years ago.  It's like a newer version of VBA, except the end user can program in any .NET language and use the .NET framework base class library.  Also, you can distribute a visual studio-like IDE, including a compiler, and debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You can write scripts in C# code and have them compiled at runtime using the [CSharpCodeCompiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0). However, in the next application *I'll* be writing that will use scripts, I'll probably be looking into adding such support through the [DLR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/hugunin/a-dynamic-language-runtime-dlr) (dynamic language runtime). That allows you to (for example) write a script in IronPython. Here is one [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/seshadripv/how-to-write-a-simple-dlr-host-in-c-using-hosting-api).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write anything, you should use one of the many already-existing [scripting languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Scripting_languages).

If by "macros" you mean things like recording user input, clicking buttons and such, you should investigate .Net [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753388.aspx). This also lets users run your application through assistive technologies like voice recognition or screen readers.